# External site in phonegap is loading too slow

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I' am trying to load an external site in Phonegap. The site normally loads in 3 - 4 seconds but its taking around 10 seconds to load in Phonegap (both in ios and android). What could be the reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap isn't really a Browser.  It's a container that runs HTML/CSS/JavaScript applications.  When you load an external website, your spawning a browser that then needs to load in memory, acquire a network connection, and retrieve the page.  This is time and resource consuming and not typically how PhoneGap is utilized.  It usually displays local pages from its package, and then utilizes AJAX to interact with a web server for RESTful type information.  The AJAX request/response time will be dependent on the network connection and the server process/response time.